# IIS virtual location path

Tags: iis-8, windows-authentication

Sorry in advance, for this seems to be a very noobish question and should be easily fixable, yet I can't work it out:

I am setting up windows authentication for a website running on IIS 8.5: The Yii framework of the website takes input like `http://localhost/mywebsite/index.php/site/login`and processes it, using the "login" action of the "site" Controller.

I flipped on URL Rewrite to have nicer URLs, leaving the URL with `/mywebsite/site/login`.

Now I need to set up windows authentication for this location. Very specifically ONLY for this very exact location. Only the `/site/login` location of mywebsite needs to have authentication. Every other location needs to have anonymous.

Since it is a "virtual location", I don't know how to do it. I can set up win-auth for files, directories, virtual directories, etc. but not for virtual locations that do not map to any file but only to a Controller/Action in Yii.

The **working** counterpart in Apache is

`<Location ~ "/site/login">
    # Insert definitions here
</Location>`

but i can't "translate this into IIS".

I have read that IIS does have the "~"  symbol but I just couldn't make it work yet. Could it be used to achieve authentication on a location basis?

I have looked around virtual directories as well, which seem to simply be a kind of "symlink" to actual folders on the harddrive. Can they be used differently to "create a virtual folder in a location that doesn't really exist to manage its properties"?

Help is much appreciated.